# How Do I Send The File Data Without Form With Ajax On Server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've coded a javascript code which nicely collects every file user wants to upload. But things turned when I added drag/drop file option.
By default, I had a code which monitored input[type='file'] change event handler and once it was detected, actions were performed and files were sent to server for upload.
But since drag/drop doesn't change the input[type='file'] value and neither I can change it programmatically due to security reasons, I'm struck how do I send files which are dragged and dropped on the site.

Here's some of my code:

```
document.getElementById('drop').addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
  e = e || window.event; 
  e.preventDefault();
  var dt    = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;
  for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    addEventHandler(reader, 'loadend', function(e, file) {
    var bin           = this.result; 
    var filename       = file.name;
    var filesize  = (file.size/1048576).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
    alert(' '+filename+' '+filesize+' '); // DEBUGGING ONLY
    console.log("YEAY");
    if(filecheck(filename)) {       // Additional Function
    step2(filesize, filename, bin); // Additional Function
    $('.btn').click(function() {    // Button to be clicked to start upload
    $('#main_img_upload').submit(); // Form with that input[type='file']
    });
    }
    else {
    alert("Wrong File");
    return false;
    }
    }.bindToEventHandler(file), false);
  }
  return false;
});
```

Obviously, it starts upload but server doesn't receive anything as no change has been made to form. But I have all the necessary details (name of file, size of file, etc..)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't even tried the drag and drop function but my idea is if I'm not mistaken you can do it just like **.ondrag(){input = get file info}** that's the way I can express since I'm not familiar with the right syntax.

Comment: This tutorial helped me greatly with a similar project: http://html5doctor.com/drag-and-drop-to-server/

Comment: @Alexdn I've got every information about the file. Just need to know how do I send the file to server. I'm unable to understand the concept other jQuery drag drop plugins are using. Simple as that :)

Comment: Check that tutorial.  There's a heading called: Automatically Uploading the File.  It's quite simple and concise example to follow.

Comment: Oh really? Then maybe you can just check out the other comment above. I just give my idea, btw thx for clarifying me hehe :)

Comment: [FormData would help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Answer (score 2):

Try out this code.

```
data.append("FileName", files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: "../",
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {

                }
            },
            error: function (er) {
                MSGBox(er);
            }

        });
    }
```